# Trigger Style Update with Binding, ReleativeSource

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp-xaml

I'm modifying RadioButton to for used as a Segmented Control, known from iOS.

Here is how it looks: 
[image]

My modified Style looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="control:SegmentRadioButton" x:Key="SegmentedRadioButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:SegmentRadioButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding SelectedTextColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TintColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And my derived Control looks like this:

```
public class SegmentRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedTextColor", 
        typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SegmentRadioButton), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedTextChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush SelectedTextColor
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(SelectedTextColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedTextColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TintColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TintColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SegmentRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTintChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush TintColor
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(TintColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(TintColorProperty, value);
    }

    public SegmentRadioButton()
    {

    }

    private static void OnTintChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            segment.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush) e.NewValue;

            if (segment.IsChecked ?? false)
            {
                // Hack to make the selected segment re-draw.
                segment.IsChecked = false;
                segment.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            if (segment.IsChecked ?? false)
            {
                // Hack to make the selected segment re-draw.
                segment.IsChecked = false;
                segment.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

QUESTION: This actually works, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and less *hacky* way to make the `TintColor` and `SelectedTextColor` update? As you can see from the two in-line comments, I'm updating/re-drawing by flipping the `IsChecked` value

Comment: I think there's no problem. You set the "IsChecked" property to false and reset to true that is to trigger the "Checked" visual state in control template. Then, your control will be able update the color timely.

Comment: Yes, that works but I feel it is a bit hacky. I ended you using the Visual State Manager instead. It still feels a little bit hacky, but the intend is more clear now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Visual State Manager and a simple Refresh.

The code is on GitHub: [Plugin.SegmentedControl](https://github.com/1iveowl/Plugin.SegmentedControl)

Here are the key parts of the code as it looks now:

```
public class SegmentRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedTextColor", 
        typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SegmentRadioButton), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedTextChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush SelectedTextColor
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(SelectedTextColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedTextColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TintColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TintColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SegmentRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTintChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush TintColor
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(TintColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(TintColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DisabledColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(SegmentRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDisabledColorChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush DisabledColor
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush) GetValue(DisabledColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(DisabledColorProperty, value);
    }


    public SegmentRadioButton()
    {
        this.IsEnabledChanged += SegmentRadioButton_IsEnabledChanged;
    }

    private void SegmentRadioButton_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            Refresh(segment);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTintChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            segment.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush) e.NewValue;
            Refresh(segment);
        }
    }


    private static void OnDisabledColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            segment.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)e.NewValue;
            Refresh(segment);
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SegmentRadioButton segment)
        {
            Refresh(segment);
        }
    }

    private static void Refresh(SegmentRadioButton segment)
    {
        // Go to "Indeterminate" State to ensure that the GotoState is refreshed even if the state is the same. 
        // Necessary because properties might have changed even when the state have not.

        VisualStateManager.GoToState(segment, "Indeterminate", false);

        if (segment.IsChecked ?? false)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(segment, segment.IsEnabled ? "Checked" : "DisabledAndChecked", false);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(segment, segment.IsEnabled ? "Unchecked" : "DisabledAndUnchecked", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="control1:SegmentRadioButton" x:Key="SegmentedRadioButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="control1:SegmentRadioButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DisabledAndChecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding DisabledColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding SelectedTextColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding DisabledColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DisabledAndUnchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding DisabledColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding DisabledColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TintColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding SelectedTextColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TintColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TintColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding TintColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```